# Split a plotly boxplot x-axis by group

Tags: r, split, plotly, boxplot, facet

I have data from `n` `group`s (in this example 2: `A` and `B`), where for each I have `m` replicates (`x`, in this example 3), with `z` measurements (`y`) for each (in this example 100):

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("A", 300),rep("B", 300)),
                 x = rep(c(rep(1, 100),rep(2, 100),rep(3, 100)), 2),
                 y = rnorm(600),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels = c("A","B"))
```

I want to use `R`'s `plotly` to plot these data as `boxplots` for each `x` in each `group`. I'd like the x-axis to first be split by `group` and then by `x`. That means that for this example, from left to right, the boxes will correspond to (`group.x`): `A.1`, `A.2`, `A.3`, `B.1`, `B.2`, `B.3`

I know I can achieve this using `plotly::subplot`, like this:

```
A.plot <- plot_ly(data = dplyr::filter(df, group == "A"),x =~ x, y =~ y, type = "box", showlegend = F, color =~ group, colors = "blue") %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Replicate", zeroline = F), yaxis = list(title = "Y", zeroline = F))

B.plot <- plot_ly(data = dplyr::filter(df, group == "B"),x =~ x, y =~ y, type = "box", showlegend = F, color =~ group, colors = "green") %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Replicate", zeroline = F), yaxis = list(title = "Y", zeroline = F))

subplot(list(A.plot, B.plot), shareY = T, shareX = F, titleX = T, titleY = T)
```

[image]

Although I can't seem to figure out how to get the x-axis label to appear only once and in the middle.

But, my question is whether this can be achieved in a single `plotly` plot (i.e., without combining a `list` of plots using `subplot`).

I thought that this might do:

```
plot_ly(data = df, x =~ x, y =~ y, split =~ group, type = "box", showlegend = F, color =~ group) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Replicate", zeroline = F), yaxis = list(title = "Y", zeroline = F))
```

But it doesn't seem like it's splitting the x-axis by `group`:
[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Add `layout(boxmode = "group")`.See: https://plot.ly/r/box-plots/#grouped-box-plots

```
plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~as.factor(cyl), y = ~mpg, color = ~as.factor(gear), type = "box") %>%
    layout(boxmode = "group")
```

[image]